# Managing global state from library

Tags: rust, state, global, api-design, idioms

I'm writing a library in Rust that implements a certain struct and methods on it. I want, however, to expose to the consumer only the methods and leave the state variables hidden, with just a few exposed through getter functions. As an example of the sort of behavior I want, here's a C snippet:

```
//library.h
void init();
void do_stuff();
int get();

//library.c
typedef struct State {
    int a,b;
} State;

State G_STATE;

void init() {} //Initialize G_STATE
void do_stuff() {} //Logic with G_STATE
int get() { return G_STATE.a; } //Returns only part of G_STATE

//main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"
int main() {
    init();
    do_stuff();
    printf(get());
    return 0;
}
```

This is clearly very unsafe and all that, but it's enough to describe the behavior. Is there an idiomatic Rust way to get this style of API? A way that, perhaps also doesn't have the same shortcomings as the snippet above in terms of memory safety and undefined lifetimes of globals?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use an opaque struct constructed by init and then have do_stuff and get be methods on it? Also what should happen if init isn't called, or if get is called on multiple threads?

Comment: Actually, an opaque struct would work just fine as instances should be thread local, don't know why I didn't think of it. However, all I know of opaque types in Rust is for FFI, but I want the same interface on Rust itself. I'm leaving this question behind and asking a new one.